# How to echo something from javascript to div class html

Tags: javascript, html, echo

Javascript

```
    function validateForm() {
        var result;
        var keywords = document.querySelectorAll('#keywords');
        [].slice.call(websites).forEach(function(website) {
            if (website.value == '') {
                website.focus();
                HERE I SAY SOMEHOW THE ERROR
                result = false;
                return true;
            }
        });  
        return result;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="error-website">HERE THE ERROR IS GETTING ECHOED</div>
```

How do i echo website in that div above and how do i add the error in that if condition.

Comment: What does `websites` variable refer to?

Comment: @VisioN It's ok i figured it out. That is not the complete function. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/rEaC8/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.error-website')[0].innerHTML = 'Website';
```

As [NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887539/null) and [VisioN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1249581/vision) has pointed , this:

```
document.querySelector('.error-website').innerHTML = 'Website';
```

is even faster , because of *"querySelector is faster unless the match is the last DomNode in the DOM"*.

Comment: Or maybe like that: `document.querySelector('.error-website').innerHTML = 'Website';`.

Comment: Working well. Trying to add an accept but don't why it doesn't take it.

Comment: @Cherniv How can your answer with `querySelectorAll()[0]` be more presice then `querySelector`?? The only difference is that `querySelector` is faster unless the match is the last DomNode in the DOM :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it would be more appropriate to use an ID not a class; the reason is that classes are meant for, well, classes (i.e. categories) of elements; however, in your case, you are dealing with one single unique element (you'll only have one), so assuming you take my advice and change to the following markup:

```
<div id="error-website">HERE THE ERROR IS GETTING ECHOED</div>
```

... it will be as simple as:

```
document.getElementById('error-website').innerHTML = "whatever <strong>you</strong> <em>like</em>";
```

Answer (score 0):

$(".error-website").text("Website")

Comment: Is there anything mentioned about jQuery?

Comment: @VisioN No Jquery, only javascript.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('error-website').innerHTML = ....

if you use an id...

Answer (score 0):

Use DOM document.getElementsByClassName

Eg.

```
function validateForm() {
      var result;
      var keywords = document.querySelectorAll('#keywords');
      [].slice.call(websites).forEach(function(website) {
    if (website.value == '') {
    website.focus();
        HERE I SAY SOMEHOW THE ERROR
        result = false;
        return true;
    }
});  
return result;

var a=validateForm();
if(a){
 document.getElementsByClassName("error-website")[0].innerHTML=a;
}
```

NOTE: getElementsByClassName() does not work in Internet Explorer 5,6,7, and 8